# Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet filter with cells with multiple values

Tags: excel, autofilter

We all know how the auto filter of Excel spreadsheet works: once the auto filter is turned on, a list of distinct values from each cell of a column shows with a checkbox in front of each value.

I am trying to find out if it is possible for one cell to have more than distinct one value and each of them still shows in the auto filter list so that when any one of them is selected in the auto filter, the row with this cell will be selected.

For example, I have a column called "developers". One of the cells of the column has two names, "John, Smith".  What should I do so that Johnn and Smith would appear in the auto filter select list, when either John or smith, or both are selected, the row with this cell will be in the result set.

Thanks.

Comment: to support @pnuts the argument accepts wildcards (eg. *, ?). so if you want all entries with John you will use this `*john*` plus the or argument to match all with Smith with this `*smith*`.

Comment: @pnuts yeah you are absolutely right. `Contains` itself is sufficient for the OP's case. my bad. :)

Comment: I tried the custom filter with the Contains key word but did not get what I was looking for. I will try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create two additional columns FirstName and LastName.  Parse Developers and load the appropriate value into each of the two new columns with a formula.  Autofilter all three columns and set up a custom filter that selects "John" from First name or "Smith" from LastName ...

... or follow pnuts' advice and use contains "John" or "Smith", which is much easier.